# imacros changing focus to second firefox window

Tags: firefox-addon, imacros

We are trying to create a script that can click on a button that appears in a second window (not a tab in the same window) but do not seem to be able to get iMacros to change its focus to a new window.
Can iMacros cross browser windows in a single script?
The webpage flow is:
- browser window directed to a URL
- Click a button in that page
- a new window is opened
- click a button in that window

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the browser show this pop-up in a new tab of the same window.

 Let's suppose that your button html code looks like this:

```
<button id="popupbut" onclick="window.open('http://popupUrlHere', '', 'width=300,height=300,left=50,top=50,menubar=no');">New window</button>
```

So, here is a macro to do the above mentioned thing:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG XPATH="id('popupbut')" EXTRACT=HTM
SET popupUrl EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/(http:.+?)['"]/)[1];")
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{popupUrl}}
```

I think this direction should be right.